# does access function check the existence of file?

Tags: c, file

The access function checks to see whether the file can be accessed in the way specified by the how argument. The how argument either can be the bitwise OR of the flags R_OK, W_OK, X_OK, or the existence test F_OK.

The return value is 0 if the access is permitted, and -1 otherwise.

if the file does not exist, Does the access return -1 too?

I wan to develop a function in which I check the existence of a file. If the following access function did it, what kind of arguments I have to put according to the standard?

```
if (access("file_example", R_OK | W_OK | X_OK) != -1)
```

**BTW:** the file I want to check if exisits by `access()` function is created by the same application. so it's created by the same user

Comment: I wonder...isn't more easy to try (reading the man page) than to write a full question on SO?

Comment: I know that test could give me some result, but I m not sure that test reflecting the right behaviour. it's nicer to see what standards says an uses things in the right wayy as specified in the standards and not as seen in the tests

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those flags would check if the file is executable, writeable and readable by the process, lots of files won't be. The flag you're looking for is F_OK. F_OK tests for the existence of the file and nothing else.

I suggest reading the man page for access. It should be documented there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use it.

```
if (access("file_example", F_OK) != -1)

int access(const char *path, int amode);
```

The value of amode is either the bitwise-inclusive OR of the access permissions to be checked (R_OK, W_OK, X_OK) or the existence test (F_OK).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with `errno` set to `ENOENT`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access), one of the errors returned is:

```
 ENOENT A component of pathname does not exist or is a dangling symbolic link.
```

Also, in the second paragraph it clearly says:

```
 F_OK tests for the existence of the file.
```